# Android: how to add a tab bar to the existing app

Tags: android

I am trying to add tab bar to my existing app. I have divided all my activities into 2 groups, each group of activities has the navigation controls.
I want to place these activities under corresponding group-1, group-2 tabs.

what is the best way of doing this.

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing particular about your app its hard to say exactly how to go about doing it, but it seems like you want to implement a `Tab Layout` and can use the following example as a guide: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: Hi Willytate, in my application say i have 4 activities (audio list, audio detail; video list, video detail) without any tabwidget. Now i need to add a tab widget with 2 tabs Audio, Video and my 2 audio, 2video activities supposed to be placed under correspoding tabs. 
I tried to add a new activity (main activity) with tabwidget, 2 tabs and i set my audio list activity to 1st tab, video list activity to 2nd tab, upto now it is fine, but when i click on a list item, the detail activity is displaying without tab bar.

is there any simple to to fix this?